# is DPS Payment Gateway a standard term

Tags: payment-gateway, moodle

I am going to setup a gateway on moodle, LMS, i have seen a plugin DPS Payment Gateway.
I have very little knowledge of payment gateways. I will coordinate with some bank payment gateways but can I setup/integrate those with this DPS Payment Gateway plugin? 
is DPS Payment Gateway a standard term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's referring to this services offered by http://www.paymentexpress.com (aka DPS)

Comment: right.. so the question in subject is how do we integrate the moodle with a payment gateway?

Comment: @asm234 - that actually isn't at all what the question says.  I suggest posting a new one if that's what you're looking for